# How is it an unmatched ")"?

Tags: python, tkinter, openfiledialog, filedialog

Consider:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


def openFile():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfile()
    file = open(filepath), 'r')
    print(file.read())
    file.close()



window = Tk()

button = Button(text="Open",command=openFile)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Error:

> C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\open a file.py"
> File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\open a file.py", line 7
> file = open(filepath), 'r')
> ^
> SyntaxError: unmatched ')'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Typo: `open(str(filepath, 'r'))` => `open(str(filepath), 'r')`. Also, apparently `filepath` is an `_io.TextIOWrapper`, which can't be converted to a string. Looks like it's already a file you can call `read()` on.

Comment: `open(filepath), 'r')` should be `open(filepath, 'r')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile) of `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile`:

> ...create an Open dialog and return the opened *file object(s)* in read-only mode.

So what `filedialog.askopenfile()` returns isn't a file path (you'd use [`askopenfilename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename) for that), but the file object you can read from:

```py
def openFile():
    file = filedialog.askopenfile()
    print(file.read())
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The unmatched `')'` comes from this line in your code which does have an unmatched `)`.

```
file = open(filepath), 'r')
```

You can access the filename string by adding `.name` to your filepath variable (and the fix for the unmatched `)`)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


def openFile():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfile()
    file = open(filepath.name, 'r')
    print(file.read())
    file.close()



window = Tk()

button = Button(text="Open",command=openFile)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```